# Fetching data from BigQuery taking very long

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to fetch data from BigQuery. Everything is working fine when i  fetch small data but when i try to fetch big data then its taking forever. any efficient way?

So far i am using this:

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'cred.json'
import google.auth
from google.cloud import bigquery

%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery

import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client

client = bigquery.Client()
```

Here is my SQL command:

```
sql = """
   SELECT bla, bla1, bla2
FROM table
"""
df = client.query(sql)
df.to_dataframe()
```

Comment: How much data are you trying to return and how long is it taking to return?

Comment: Its about 2 million rows

Comment: How much data in MBs or GBs and how long is _"forever"_?

Comment: Its about 4.5GB.. forever mean that i tried to wait about 45 - 60mins

Comment: You could try the BigQuery Storage API and see if that's quicker. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/

Comment: What's your bandwidth? What your CPU capability? Did you try on Cloud Shell? Is it better?

Comment: I tried everyhting what yo mentioned. I am using VM from GCP.  I have done everything but by just migrating the data into SQL instance and its more faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get BigQuery data into a dataframe magnitudes faster by changing the method.

Check how these options are reflected in the chart:

- A: `to_dataframe()` - Uses BigQuery tabledata.list API.
- B: `to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client)`, package version 1.16.0 - Uses BigQuery Storage API with Avro data format.
- C: `to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client)`, package version 1.17.0 - Uses BigQuery Storage API with Arrow data format.
- D: `to_arrow(bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client).to_pandas()`, package version 1.17.0 - Uses BigQuery Storage API with Arrow data format.

[image]

Note how you can go from >500 seconds to ~20 by using `to_arrow(bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client).to_pandas()`.

See https://medium.com/google-cloud/announcing-google-cloud-bigquery-version-1-17-0-1fc428512171

Comment: Hi @Felipe . First of all really thanks for your answer and its seems really good but i tried also before using pandas_gbq but whenever i try to import this then i am getting this error... `ImportError: cannot import name 'lzip'`

Comment: Can you post a new question for that? Perhaps Tim can answer it

Comment: I just posted the new question/. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766605/importing-error-of-panda-gbq-in-vmvirtual-machine-in-google-cloud-platform

Comment: Hi Felipe. This answer saved me so much time.  Thank you so much.  How is 'to_arrow()' so much faster?